# CSS - How to increase width of the dropdown using CSS?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css, width

In the code I have checkbox, when checked the dropdown is displayed.
If 1st value of dropdown is selected the next dropdown is displayed next to it.
The problem is I am unable to increase the width of the dropdown and the full text is not visible.

```
   <div class="flex items-center w-full">
                        <div id="data" fxLayout="row" class="w-1/3">
                            <mat-checkbox formControlName="allowData"
                                >Allow</mat-checkbox
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div
                            *ngIf="form2.value.extendedProperties.allowData"
                            fxLayout="row"
                            fxLayoutAlign="start center"
                            fxLayoutGap="16px"
                            class="w-1/4"
                        >
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <mat-select
                                    placeholder="Amazon"
                                    formControlName="dataCharged"
                                >
                                    <mat-option
                                        *ngFor="let info of dataCharged.values"
                                        [value]="info"
                                        >{{ dataCharged.descriptions[info] }}</mat-option
                                    >
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <mat-form-field
                                *ngIf="
                                    form2.value.extendedProperties.dataCharged ==
                                    dataCharged.nominationAmazon
                                "
                            >
                                <mat-select placeholder="Select" formControlName="nominationAmazonId">
                                    <mat-option [value]="0">None</mat-option>
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let amazon of amazons" [value]="amazon.id">
                                        {{.name }}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <mat-checkbox
                                fxFlex="40"
                                *ngIf="
                                    form2.value.extendedProperties.dataCharged ==
                                    dataCharged.classEntryAmazon
                                "
                                formControlName="refundClassEntryAmazon"
                            >
                                Refund
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `w-full` class will make the inner element take up the full width of its parent, regardless of the parent's width.

Here's an example:

```html
<div class="w-2/5">
  <div class="w-full">
    <!-- Content inside div with full width -->
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the outer `div` has a width of 2/5 of its parent, and the inner `div` will take the full width of the outer `div` due to the application of `w-full`. This allows the content inside the inner `div` to stretch across the entire width of its containing block. Adjust these classes based on your specific layout requirements.